# Array of integers with leading zeros - weird results

Tags: php, arrays

Edit: I should have noted that I am aware I could use quotes. Thank you for the answers, I had never heard of Octals.

I noticed something and this is more of a curiosity question rather than needing help. Why does this happen?

```
print_r(array(00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,010,011,012,013,014,015,016,017,018,019,020));

Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 6
    [7] => 7
    [8] => 0
    [9] => 0
    [10] => 8
    [11] => 9
    [12] => 10
    [13] => 11
    [14] => 12
    [15] => 13
    [16] => 14
    [17] => 15
    [18] => 1
    [19] => 1
    [20] => 16
)
```

Once it hits 8, everything is messed up. What causes this?

Comment: One word.... __OCTAL__ - http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php - don't give numbers leading zeroes unless you know what you're doing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The numbers with leading zero is understood as OCTAL numbers by PHP.

In case you don't know what OCTAL numbers are, read [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal). In short, they are numbers with base-8. The numbers we use in daily life are 10-based.

Now, As you noted, `08` and `09` gives `0`. Because they are not valid Octal numbres. And thus `010` is actually `8` in Decimal, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use integers with leading zeros you have to store them as stings in PHP, otherwise they can turn into octals.

Like so:

```
array('01', '02', '03');
```